# fake js into thinking the url has an extra paramenter

Tags: javascript, url, redirect, mbox

i have a script included into my site that reads a variable on the url like www.test.com/?mboxDisable=1 so i was wondering how to fake that so on www.test.com js would "think" there is mboxDisable=1 
I know coldfusion and i could that by just using  on the first line but how to do that with js? I tried the document.location.href += "mboxDisable=1" but then js refreshes the page to www.test.com/?mboxDisable=1
Is there a way to make js think that the parameter in the url without actually being in the url?

I forgot to mention the usage:
I have a cookie that i check to see if the user wants to disable mbox or not so in pseudo code would be something like 
if cookieIsSet
urlAppend("mboxDisable=1")
endif

The auto generated code that i can't change gets the info from document.location. any way to edit that without refreshing the page? No html5 and no jquery. Can use coldfusion and js.

Comment: Where's the code that reads the variable? That would be the place to handle this. If the variable is blank, then default to whatever `mboxDisable=1` is supposed to do.

Comment: Can't you change the code so say if it is not there you use a default? That would seem to be the logical way to do it.

Comment: the code that reads it is inside an auto generated file... a black box if you will. i cant change it and the only way to disable it is to append mboxDisable=1 to every single page you go to. I could just redirect in coldfusion but then id lose all the post data which is unnaceptable
@Matt: it cant be just blank because that is an option blank means mboxes are enabled

Comment: @user1824583: You might just need to shine a light in that black box then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use HTML5 pushState using which the URL of the page can be modified without refreshing the page.

[Link showing an example](http://html5demos.com/history)

Comment: html5 doesnt work on IE and thats half the ppl that look at the site

Answer (score 0):

Use a URL hash instead of a parameter:

`mysite.com?mboxDisable=1` becomes: `mysite.com#mboxDisable=1`

You can then use `document.location.hash` to both read and set this parameter without refreshing. Of course your code will need to be able to read this value instead.

All other methods to change the URL will result in loading a new page.

Comment: i dont have control over the file that reads it. its an auto generated file like a black box

Comment: I guess you're really stuck.